# Attempting to get data from Entry widget(tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
 def AppendModule():
        Message = Label(GUIWindows.root, text="please type the ID of the module you want to append").grid(rows=6, column=0)
        ModuleInput = Entry(GUIWindows.root).grid(rows=6, column=0)
        ModuleInput.pack()
        AcceptButton = Button(GUIWindows.root, text='Enter ID', command=ModuleInput).grid(rows=8, column=0)
        e = ModuleInput.get
        print(e)
```

So this function is suppose to prompt the user to type the name of the module in the text box and then store what the user wrote as a variable. I'm getting the error (AttritubeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack').
So I did a bit of research and I was told to use the .pack to store the data and then use the .get to retrieve it. Though that doesn't seem to work. Any Suggestions?

Comment: You are using both grid() and pack() on your widget. Don't do that. This error is telling you that your NoneType object (IE the grid() is returning NULL) does not contain a pack method. Delete the pack and move the grid to a new line.

Comment: Thank you for the tip I will apply that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forgot to add parentheses. But even if you did this, you are still trying to get entry input right after creating it.
2. As @Mike - SMT said, you are using both .grid() and .pack() methods, which is not allowed.
3. You're trying to set ModuleInput ( which is Entry object ) as command attribute in AcceptButton. You should make a function or method that prints entry input and link it as command in AcceptButton.

So, try this:

```
def printTextInEntry():
    print(ModuleInput.get())

def AppendModule2():
    global ModuleInput
    Message = Label(GUIWindows.root, text="please type the ID of the module you want to append").grid(rows=6, column=0)
    ModuleInput = Entry(GUIWindows.root)
    ModuleInput.grid(rows=6, column=0)
    AcceptButton = Button(GUIWindows.root, text='Enter ID', command=printTextInEntry)
    AcceptButton.grid(rows=8, column=0)
```